# How to convert this html table to div?

Tags: html, css

can anyone advise how do i convert the below html table into div? I tried to do some googling but not able to find a specific examples on this. Would appreciate if anyone can provide me with some sample codes or point me to the right direction.

Thanks

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>   

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        List of news
                     </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">
                        Title
                    </td>
                    <td width="5%">
                        :
                    </td>
                    <td width="75%">
                        Name of title
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        Description
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        :
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        Content of description
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Your last two table rows are not correct. Please provide the correct table structure.

Comment: Hi i have made changes accordingly can advise further on the div layout to adopt?

Comment: Please improve your second row. As it is more important to define first what actual table conversion you are looking for.

Comment: My apologies. Have removed that row as well.

Comment: what have you tried? this is a very open ended question in that the answer could be lot so of different things.

Comment: do you mean there are many ways of converting into divs? Actually i am just looking for a conversion that will work well on old mobile devices also that all

Comment: @user1503699 : check my answer n visit demo link, is this u looking for!

Comment: Hi i tested your code sample. It only works correctly in internet explorer. Does not display correctly in google chrome and firefox

Comment: http://programmerscalculator.apphb.com/Home/HtmlToDiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/TdAWY/

demo with content
http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/TdAWY/1/

```
<div class="headDiv">
        <div class="c1 w1" >
            sd
        </div>
        <div class="c1 w20">s
        </div>
        <div class="c1 w5"> s
        </div>
        <div class="c1 w75">s
        </div>
         <div class="c1 w20">s
        </div>
        <div class="c1 w5"> s
        </div>
        <div class="c1 w75">s
        </div>

    </div>​

.c1
{
float:left;

}

.headDiv
{
width:100%;
border:1px soild blue;
}
.w75
{
width:75%;
height:50px;

border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.w20
{
width:20%;
height:50px;

border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.w5
{
width:5%;
height:50px;
background-color:Yellow;
border-bottom:1px solid;
}

.w1
{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:pink;
border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [tabletodivconverter.com/](http://www.tabletodivconverter.com/) to convert html tables to div.